# What is the best way to deal with data in GAE?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, google-app-engine

I have a website based on GAE and use Django to create forms for user inputs. In the future, users will be able to build their own data or use (modify) the build-in data to perform some calculations, which means this data structure will be frequently visited (read and write).
So my question is what data structure should I use(google cloud sql, datastore, etc)? Should I use data structure provided by GAE or Django or something else?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hummm. . . Have you followed the GAE getting started guide?

I think that you are talking about datastore
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/

This is provided by google and optimized for cloud applications.
I used it a bit, and must say it is quite straightforward once you get used to it :).

And you might also like this :
https://sites.google.com/site/io/rapid-development-with-python-django-and-google-app-engine

Comment: Apparently you already tagged gae-datastore. Perhaps I'm wrong concerning your question then

Comment: The video seems very helpful. I have removed the gae-datastore tag. So I am open to all the options. My other concern is if this website uses as much as features of GAE, does that mean it is "locked" and could be migrated?

Comment: Well, I would say the exact opposite. If your architecture is good enough the  datastore is finally simply an interface. Create functions such as get_values and set_values. If tomorrow you decide to change options, those are the only one meant to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't put nearly enough information down to answer the question properly.  Google offers both Cloud SQL and the HR Datastore because they each of their own pros/cons.  We can't answer your question without knowing what the parameters are to lean towards one or the other.

Cloud SQL works well if you are porting an App over that is already SQL based.  Or if you know your app requires relational semantics provided by SQL.  The datastore scales well for huge amounts of data beyond SQL, but is not directly compatible with SQL, and the eventually consistent semantics may not be good for some applications.

You added in a comment that you're concerned about migration, that affects the answer a lot as well.  Cloud SQL can easily be migrated to other SQL backends.  The datastore, not so much, though if you use Django-nonrel, it can be migrated to a MongoDB backend.

If you want a good answer, you'll need to provide more information about what your site does, the types of data, the relations between data, and how big you expect to scale.  Also, what reasons do you think you'll have for migrating, and where do you plan to migrate to?